How to Split a String by Delimiters and Handle Empty Values as NULL in Oracle PL/SQL?
I have a string in Oracle PL/SQL that looks like this:
280,1,2,3,3 | 120,,0,2,3 | 280,1,2,3,3

Each section is separated by a | character, and within each section, values are separated by commas. The challenge I’m facing is correctly extracting the values, and for missing or empty values
For example, the data I expect is:

Country ID: 280, EIN: 1, SSN: 2, ITIN: 3, ATIN: 3
Country ID: 120, EIN: NULL, SSN: 0, ITIN: 2, ATIN: 3
Country ID: 280, EIN: 1, SSN: 2, ITIN: 3, ATIN: 3

Here’s what I have tried:
DECLARE
    v_entry VARCHAR2(500); 
    v_countries VARCHAR2(500) := '280,1,2,3,3 | 120,,0,2,3 | 280,1,2,3,3';
    v_country_id VARCHAR2(50);
    v_ein VARCHAR2(50);
    v_ssn VARCHAR2(50);
    v_itin VARCHAR2(50);
    v_atin VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1 .. REGEXP_COUNT(v_countries, '\|') + 1 LOOP
        v_entry := REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_countries, '[^|]+', 1, i);
    
        v_country_id := REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_entry, '([^,]*)', 1, 1);
        v_ein := REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_entry, '([^,]*)', 1, 2);
        v_ssn := REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_entry, '([^,]*)', 1, 3);
        v_itin := REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_entry, '([^,]*)', 1, 4);
        v_atin := REGEXP_SUBSTR(v_entry, '([^,]*)', 1, 5);

        v_country_id := CASE WHEN v_country_id IS NULL OR v_country_id = '' THEN 'NULL' ELSE v_country_id END;
        v_ein := CASE WHEN v_ein IS NULL OR v_ein = '' THEN 'NULL' ELSE v_ein END;
        v_ssn := CASE WHEN v_ssn IS NULL OR v_ssn = '' THEN 'NULL' ELSE v_ssn END;
        v_itin := CASE WHEN v_itin IS NULL OR v_itin = '' THEN 'NULL' ELSE v_itin END;
        v_atin := CASE WHEN v_atin IS NULL OR v_atin = '' THEN 'NULL' ELSE v_atin END;

        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Country ID: ' || v_country_id);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EIN: ' || v_ein);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SSN: ' || v_ssn);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ITIN: ' || v_itin);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ATIN: ' || v_atin);
    END LOOP;
END;

The issue:
I'm expecting to handle empty fields between commas as NULL, but the output doesn’t reflect this correctly.
For example, for the second section 120,,0,2,3, I expect:

Country ID: 120
EIN: NULL
SSN: 0
ITIN: 2
ATIN: 3

But instead, I get unexpected behavior where either values aren’t correctly assigned or the NULL values don’t show up properly.

Can you use a space rather than nothing in case no value should be set? Then this would be trivial, you would just use + rather than * and check for a space rather than nothing, see this sample fiddle

@JonasMetzler I tried using + as well, but it still didn’t show up properly.

The fiddle I linked proves it works as expected, doesn't it?

You can use simple string expressions:
DECLARE
  v_entry      VARCHAR2(500); 
  v_countries  VARCHAR2(500) := '280,1,2,3,3 | 120,,0,2,3 | 280,1,2,3,3';
  v_country_id VARCHAR2(50);
  v_ein        VARCHAR2(50);
  v_ssn        VARCHAR2(50);
  v_itin       VARCHAR2(50);
  v_atin       VARCHAR2(50);
  v_spos       PLS_INTEGER := 1;
  v_epos       PLS_INTEGER;
  v_entry_spos PLS_INTEGER;
  v_entry_epos PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
  LOOP
    v_epos  := INSTR(v_countries, '|', v_spos);
    v_entry := CASE v_epos
               WHEN 0
               THEN SUBSTR(v_countries, v_spos)
               ELSE SUBSTR(v_countries, v_spos, v_epos - v_spos)
               END;
    v_entry_spos := 1;
    v_entry_epos := INSTR(v_entry, ',', v_entry_spos);
    v_country_id := SUBSTR(v_entry, v_entry_spos, v_entry_epos - v_entry_spos);
    v_entry_spos := v_entry_epos + 1;
    v_entry_epos := INSTR(v_entry, ',', v_entry_spos);
    v_ein        := SUBSTR(v_entry, v_entry_spos, v_entry_epos - v_entry_spos);
    v_entry_spos := v_entry_epos + 1;
    v_entry_epos := INSTR(v_entry, ',', v_entry_spos);
    v_ssn        := SUBSTR(v_entry, v_entry_spos, v_entry_epos - v_entry_spos);
    v_entry_spos := v_entry_epos + 1;
    v_entry_epos := INSTR(v_entry, ',', v_entry_spos);
    v_itin       := SUBSTR(v_entry, v_entry_spos, v_entry_epos - v_entry_spos);
    v_entry_spos := v_entry_epos + 1;
    v_atin       := SUBSTR(v_entry, v_entry_spos);
    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Country ID: ' || COALESCE(v_country_id, 'NULL'));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EIN: ' || COALESCE(v_ein, 'NULL'));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SSN: ' || COALESCE(v_ssn, 'NULL'));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ITIN: ' || COALESCE(v_itin, 'NULL'));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ATIN: ' || COALESCE(v_atin, 'NULL'));
    EXIT WHEN v_epos = 0;
    v_spos := v_epos + 1;
  END LOOP;
END;
/

Which outputs:
Country ID: 280
EIN: 1
SSN: 2
ITIN: 3
ATIN: 3 
Country ID:  120
EIN: NULL
SSN: 0
ITIN: 2
ATIN: 3 
Country ID:  280
EIN: 1
SSN: 2
ITIN: 3
ATIN: 3


If you want to use regular expressions then:
DECLARE
  v_countries  VARCHAR2(500) := '280,1,2,3,3 | 120,,0,2,3 | 280,1,2,3,3';
  v_country_id VARCHAR2(50);
  v_ein        VARCHAR2(50);
  v_ssn        VARCHAR2(50);
  v_itin       VARCHAR2(50);
  v_atin       VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1 .. REGEXP_COUNT(v_countries, '(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)(\||$)') LOOP
    v_country_id := REGEXP_SUBSTR( v_countries, '(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)(\||$)', 1, i, NULL, 1);
    v_ein        := REGEXP_SUBSTR( v_countries, '(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)(\||$)', 1, i, NULL, 2);
    v_ssn        := REGEXP_SUBSTR( v_countries, '(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)(\||$)', 1, i, NULL, 3);
    v_itin       := REGEXP_SUBSTR( v_countries, '(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)(\||$)', 1, i, NULL, 4);
    v_atin       := REGEXP_SUBSTR( v_countries, '(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)(\||$)', 1, i, NULL, 5);
    
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Country ID: ' || COALESCE(v_country_id, 'NULL'));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('EIN: ' || COALESCE(v_ein, 'NULL'));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('SSN: ' || COALESCE(v_ssn, 'NULL'));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ITIN: ' || COALESCE(v_itin, 'NULL'));
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ATIN: ' || COALESCE(v_atin, 'NULL'));
  END LOOP;
END;
/

Which outputs the same.

If you want it as a query then:
WITH data (value) AS (
  SELECT '280,1,2,3,3 | 120,,0,2,3 | 280,1,2,3,3' FROM DUAL
),
countries (value, i, max_i, country_id, ein, ssn, itin, atin) AS (
  SELECT value,
         1,
         REGEXP_COUNT(value, '(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)(\||$)'),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 1, NULL, 1),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 1, NULL, 2),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 1, NULL, 3),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 1, NULL, 4),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)(\||$)', 1, 1, NULL, 5)
  FROM   data
UNION ALL
  SELECT value,
         i + 1,
         max_i,
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)(\||$)', 1, i + 1, NULL, 1),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)(\||$)', 1, i + 1, NULL, 2),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)(\||$)', 1, i + 1, NULL, 3),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)(\||$)', 1, i + 1, NULL, 4),
         REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, '(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?),(.*?)(\||$)', 1, i + 1, NULL, 5)
  FROM   countries
  WHERE  i < max_i
)
SELECT i, country_id, ein, ssn, itin, atin
FROM   countries;

Which outputs:



I
COUNTRY_ID
EIN
SSN
ITIN
ATIN




1
280
1
2
3
3


2
120
null
0
2
3


3
280
1
2
3
3



fiddle

Here is another option. If you have APEX installed in your database (that is a no-cost option) then you have access to a number of useful pl/sql api's. To handle delimited strings, use APEX_STRING.SPLIT:
DECLARE
  l_record apex_t_varchar2;
  l_vars apex_t_varchar2;
  l_string varchar2(1000) :=  '280,1,2,3,3 | 120,,0,2,3 | 280,1,2,3,3';

BEGIN
  l_record := apex_string.split(l_string,'|');
  FOR r IN 1 .. l_record.COUNT LOOP
    l_vars := apex_string.split(l_record(r),',');
    dbms_output.put_line('Country ID:' ||l_vars(1));
    dbms_output.put_line('EIN       :' ||l_vars(2));
    dbms_output.put_line('SSN       :' ||l_vars(3));
    dbms_output.put_line('ITIN      :' ||l_vars(4));
    dbms_output.put_line('ATIN      :' ||l_vars(5));
  END LOOP;
END;
/

Country ID:280
EIN       :1
SSN       :2
ITIN      :3
ATIN      :3 
Country ID: 120
EIN       :
SSN       :0
ITIN      :2
ATIN      :3 
Country ID: 280
EIN       :1
SSN       :2
ITIN      :3
ATIN      :3


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.


You can play with this one and tune the xmlquery to your needs:
with data(s) as(
    select '280,1,2,3,3 | 120,,0,2,3 | 280,1,2,3,3' from dual
)
select s, section, key, value
from data d,
xmltable(
  'for $section at $sectionIdx in fn:tokenize($X,"\|")
    return(
            for $key at $keyIdx in fn:tokenize("Country ID,EIN,SSN,ITIN,ATIN",","),
            $value at $valueIdx in fn:tokenize(fn:normalize-space($section), ",")
            where ($keyIdx = $valueIdx) 
            return <item><section>{$sectionIdx}</section><key>{$key}</key><value>{$value}</value></item>
    )
    '
  passing s as "X"
  columns 
    section number path '/item/section',
    key varchar2(12) path '/item/key',
    value varchar2(12) path '/item/value'
  ) t
;


280,1,2,3,3 | 120,,0,2,3 | 280,1,2,3,3  1   Country ID  280
280,1,2,3,3 | 120,,0,2,3 | 280,1,2,3,3  1   EIN 1
280,1,2,3,3 | 120,,0,2,3 | 280,1,2,3,3  1   SSN 2
280,1,2,3,3 | 120,,0,2,3 | 280,1,2,3,3  1   ITIN    3
280,1,2,3,3 | 120,,0,2,3 | 280,1,2,3,3  1   ATIN    3
280,1,2,3,3 | 120,,0,2,3 | 280,1,2,3,3  2   Country ID  120
280,1,2,3,3 | 120,,0,2,3 | 280,1,2,3,3  2   EIN 
280,1,2,3,3 | 120,,0,2,3 | 280,1,2,3,3  2   SSN 0
280,1,2,3,3 | 120,,0,2,3 | 280,1,2,3,3  2   ITIN    2
280,1,2,3,3 | 120,,0,2,3 | 280,1,2,3,3  2   ATIN    3
280,1,2,3,3 | 120,,0,2,3 | 280,1,2,3,3  3   Country ID  280
280,1,2,3,3 | 120,,0,2,3 | 280,1,2,3,3  3   EIN 1
280,1,2,3,3 | 120,,0,2,3 | 280,1,2,3,3  3   SSN 2
280,1,2,3,3 | 120,,0,2,3 | 280,1,2,3,3  3   ITIN    3
280,1,2,3,3 | 120,,0,2,3 | 280,1,2,3,3  3   ATIN    3

